# D3 x axis remove vertical bars

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Trying to achieve X-axis as below:
[image]

But the default implementation is as here :

[image]

The implementation looks like :

```
baseGroup.append("g")
              .attr("class", "xaxis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(5," + (height - marginBottom) + ")")
              .style({ 'stroke': 'Black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '0.5px','font-size': '14px', 'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges'})
              .call(xBar);
```

Want to remove vertical bars on each tick.
Can anyone suggest me the right way to style D3 x axis ?

Comment: Since you are passing an object to `style` I assume you are using D3 v3, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, version 3.5.17

Comment: You can try for this css too:- .xaxis line { stroke-opacity: 0 }

Answer (score 6):

According to [D3 changes documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) the outerTickSize and innerTickSize have been renamed to [tickSizeInner](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickSizeInner) and [tickSizeOuter](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickSizeOuter) respectively.

Therefore, updating Gerardo Furtado answer, the snippet would be:

```
var xBar = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(scale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
  .tickSizeInner(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For setting the size of the inner ticks, you have to use `axis.innerTickSize`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#innerTickSize):

> If size is specified, sets the inner tick size to the specified value and returns the axis. If size is not specified, returns the current inner tick size, which defaults to 6.

Therefore, in your case, the axis generator should be like this:

```
var xBar = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .innerTickSize(0)
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([20, 480]);

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(scale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .innerTickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(10);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .style({
    'stroke': 'gray',
    'fill': 'none',
    'stroke-width': '1px',
    'font-size': '14px',
    'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges'
  })
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieve through **css properties**. Reduce [**stroke-opacity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-opacity) of the axis tick line to **0**

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([20, 480]);

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(scale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickPadding(10);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .style({
    'stroke': 'gray',
    'fill': 'none',
    'stroke-width': '1px',
    'font-size': '14px',
    'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges'
  })
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
```

```css
.x.axis>.tick> line {
 stroke-opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='500' height='200'>
```